# Javascript: Subtracting a whole integer from a integer with a decimal alters the decimal value?

Tags: javascript

The goal is to isolate the decimal value (with simply turning the integer into a string and splitting it).

To that affect I have:

```
var x = 1001.1;
var roundedDown = Math.floor(x); // Produces 1001
var decimal = x - roundedDown;
```

The expected value of `decimal` should be 0.1 (1001.1 - 1001). But instead I get 0.0999999 recurring.

I have tried with `Math.trunc` as well but get the same results.

Would anyone know why this is?

Comment: There is no such thing as "integer with a decimal". It's like "vegetarian goulash with pork".

Comment: What's the correct term, just out of interest? Simply integer?

Comment: From mathematical perspective, a [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number). From a computing perspective, a [floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Floating-point_numbers) ("float" for short). Integers (both [mathematically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) and [computationally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science))), by definition, can't have a [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part).